# BigDecimal acting weird

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal a1

```
BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal("0");
System.out.println(a1) //"0.0"
```

When I do

```
a1.pow(2)
```

I and print the value I get "0.00"
In my program, I loop this, and that causes problems because each time it loops, it doubles the trailing 0's. In order for my program to work as intended, it could get 2^100 trailing zeros which slows down performance and takes lots of memory. I have tried

```
a1.stripTrailingZeros();
```

but it still stores the useless zeros and takes a long time to compute.
In this, I need to maximize performance, so converting to a string and doing string manipulation might not be the best way. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You don't want a1=0 since 0 to any positive power is 0. Am I missing something? Maybe a1=10, since you mention trailing zeroes?

Comment: If you don't want trailing zeros set the scale accordingly.

Comment: I was using 0 as an example. I use many other values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is immutable (and doesn't operate in place). Change

```
a1.pow(2);
```

to (something like)

```
a1 = a1.pow(2);
```

Of course, `0 * 0` is `0`. So, to get a non-zero number; you could do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal("2");
    a1 = a1.pow(2);
    System.out.println(a1);
}
```

And I get (the expected)

```
4
```

Comment: I did set it so it would do `a1 = a1.pow(2);`. I just forgot to set it like that in my example

Comment: I realized what I had done. I had forgotten to do `a1 = a1.stripTrailingZeros`();. Thanks